# How can I run this SQL query in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I am trying to run this SQL query in many ways in laravel but it shows error.

```
SELECT * FROM reservas WHERE cliente_id = 2201 AND dia >= '2020-10-15' GROUP BY dia
```

I have tried to run this query but I get a violation error

```
DB::select('SELECT * FROM reservas WHERE cliente_id = :id AND dia >= :date GROUP BY dia', ['id' => $id, 'date' => $date]);
```

The variables that I send have data, that is, the error does not come from empty variables, far from it, but the error comes from the query.
It should be noted that this query does work in SQL.

Comment: Well your current attempt is a raw SQL query, so at the very least you should be using `selectRaw`, not `select`.

Comment: It shows me the following error when substituting select for selectRaw `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::selectRaw()`

Comment: Why are you using `GROUP BY` without selecting any aggregates?  Your current query does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to write your query like** `groupBy(DB::raw('dia'))`

```
\DB::table('reservas')->where('cliente_id',$id)->where('dia',$date)->get()->groupBy('dia');
```

You need to change false in `config/database.php` Like `strict => false` if your groupBy not working properly.

Hope its work!!

Answer (score 0):

@Cristian you need to use **DB::raw** inside **DB::select**

using like that

```
DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM reservas WHERE cliente_id = :id AND dia >= :date GROUP BY dia"), ['id' => $id, 'date' => $date]);
```

other wise used this if you don't want to set strict type false.

```
DB::table('reservas')->where('cliente_id',$id)->where('dia',$date)->get()->groupBy('dia');
```

Comment: But is a raw query the best option here in general?  Assuming fluent builder supports parameters, wouldn't it make more sense to use that instead?

Comment: `GROUP BY` with `SELECT *` is generally forbidden.

Comment: This is the only way to use raw sql querry in Laravel @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: I get the following error `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'propuesta.reservas.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: SELECT * FROM reservas WHERE cliente_id = :id AND dia >= :date GROUP BY dia)`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you are right but  he mention in question how to run sql query .

Comment: @Cristian you need to set false `config/database.php`  strict => false